# How to keep permissions for protected sheets in Google Sheets when making a copy of the entire google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet file with multiple subsheets where I have protected the different subsheets so that the user can only enter input in certain cells. I havde addede the permissions that everyone within my organization are still able to edit the entire subsheet, and that works fine.

When we share the Google Sheet with clients, they can only edit the cells I have defined, and everyone else within my organization can edit everything in the subsheet - it works as intended.

But when I make a copy of the entire Google Sheet, e.g. because I want to make a new version for a specific client, it loses some of the settings...

The subsheets in the new Google Sheet file are still protected, and the cells I chose to be able for user to input in are also still working fine.

But the permission of all the protected sub sheets have changed, so now it os only me than can edit the subsheets and not everyone in my organization (as I had chosen in the original Google Sheet file)...?

How can I copy the Google Sheet file and keep the exact same permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose **File > Make a copy**, tick the **☑️   Share it with the same people** checkbox.